# How to create actor props with Router in Akka 2.5

Tags: java, akka

in Akka 2.0 we used to have

```
List<String> routeePaths = actorRefs.stream()
                    .map(e -> e.path().toString())
                    .collect(toList());

Props routerProps = Props.empty().withRouter(new BroadcastRouter(routeePaths));
```

But in Akka 2.5, BroadcastRouter and some other old Routers are not there any more. Whats the proper way to add those routing behavior to actors.

Answer (score 1):

Akka 2.5 has [`BroadcastRoutingLogic`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5.2/akka/routing/BroadcastRoutingLogic.html). The examples below are from the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.2/java/routing.html):

```
Router router;
{
  List<Routee> routees = new ArrayList<Routee>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ActorRef r = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Worker.class));
    getContext().watch(r);
    routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(r));
  }
  router = new Router(new BroadcastRoutingLogic(), routees);
}
```

You can also use a [`BroadcastPool`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5.2/index.html?akka/routing/BroadcastPool.html) or [`BroadcastGroup`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5.2/akka/routing/BroadcastGroup.html):

`BroadcastPool` defined in configuration:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /parent/router13 {
    router = broadcast-pool
    nr-of-instances = 5
  }
}

ActorRef router13 = getContext().actorOf(FromConfig.getInstance().props(Props.create(Worker.class)), "router13");
```

`BroadcastPool` defined in code:

```
ActorRef router14 = getContext().actorOf(new BroadcastPool(5).props(Props.create(Worker.class)), "router14");
```

`BroadcastGroup` defined in configuration:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /parent/router15 {
    router = broadcast-group
    routees.paths = ["/user/workers/w1", "/user/workers/w2", "/use/workers/w3"]
  }
}

ActorRef router15 = getContext().actorOf(FromConfig.getInstance().props(), "router15");
```

`BroadcastGroup` defined in code:

```
List<String> paths = Arrays.asList("/user/workers/w1", "/user/workers/w2", "/user/workers/w3");
ActorRef router16 = getContext().actorOf(new BroadcastGroup(paths).props(), "router16");
```